# Remove array if meets certain conditions

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to work out how I can remove all timestamps which have a certain reservation id after them.
Currently I can unset only based on timestamp and not check whether reservation id is there. This is part of the php code snippet:

```
$pending_prep_dates_array  = array();
    
    
        $check_in_date  = get_post_meta( $resID, 'reservation_checkin_date', true );
        $check_out_date = get_post_meta( $resID, 'reservation_checkout_date', true );
        
        $check_in_prep = new DateTime($check_in_date);
        $check_in_prep->sub(new DateInterval('P2D')); // P1D means a period of 1 day
        $check_in_final = $check_in_prep->getTimestamp();
        
        $check_out_prep = new DateTime($check_out_date);
        $check_out_prep->add(new DateInterval('P2D')); // P1D means a period of 1 day
        $check_out_final = $check_out_prep->getTimestamp();
        
        for ($currentDate = $check_in_final; $currentDate <= $check_out_final; $currentDate += (86400)) {
        
        $Store = $currentDate;
        unset($pending_prep_dates_array[$Store]);
```

This is how it is stored in array in my database:

a:15{i:1652054400;i:8997;i:1652140800;i:8999;i:1652227200;i:8999;i:1652313600;i:8999;i:1652400000;i:8999;i:1652486400;i:8999;i:1652572800;i:8999;i:1651536000;i:8993;i:1651622400;i:8993;i:1651708800;i:8993;i:1651795200;i:8993;i:1651881600;i:8993;i:1651968000;i:8997;i:1651363200;i:8993;i:1651449600;i:8993;}

So to clarify, how can I only remove timestamps if reservation id is for example 8999?

Thanks

Comment: _"This is how it is stored in array in my database"_ - what exactly is "it"? You can't be talking about `$pending_prep_dates_array`, I suppose, because you are accessing that with a date value as key, but the shown serialized array is a simple one with a zero-based index.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the data and build a new array with the ID(s) removed:

```
<?php

$raw = 'a:15:{i:1652054400;i:8997;i:1652140800;i:8999;i:1652227200;i:8999;i:1652313600;i:8999;i:1652400000;i:8999;i:1652486400;i:8999;i:1652572800;i:8999;i:1651536000;i:8993;i:1651622400;i:8993;i:1651708800;i:8993;i:1651795200;i:8993;i:1651881600;i:8993;i:1651968000;i:8997;i:1651363200;i:8993;i:1651449600;i:8993;}';

$data = unserialize($raw);

$ids_to_remove = [8999, 8993];
$data_with_id_removed = [];

foreach ($data as $timestamp => $id) {
    if (in_array($id, $ids_to_remove))
        continue;
    
    $data_with_id_removed[$timestamp] = $id;
}

var_dump($data_with_id_removed);
```

Result (all timestamps with id 8999 and 8993 removed)

```
array(2) {
  [1652054400]=>
  int(8997)
  [1651968000]=>
  int(8997)
}
```